# Iphone makefile dropping last quote on loading

Tags: iphone, makefile, program-entry-point, double-quotes, toolchain

I am currently trying to build an iPhone app that I have developed using the iPhone toolchain. When I finished creating the makefile it was giving me this error when it tried to load my .o files together:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Upon looking at the shell code it was trying to execute, I determined that it dropped the last quote so I made a quick fix to my makefile. Upon loading, it gave me the following error:

Undefined symbols:

```
  "_main", referenced from:
      __start in crt1.10.5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** ["Autotune] Error 1
```

If I read this correctly it cannot find my main function, but it is clearly defined in main.mm. I would like to keep my project closed source, but I am willing to show certain, non-vital parts of my code. I don't see why it is not compiling; it worked fine on Xcode. Did my change to the Makefile somehow cause it to not load the _main symbol? How can I fix this problem? I am quite stumped.

Here is my Makefile:

```
PROJECTNAME="MyAppName"
APPFOLDER=$(PROJECTNAME).app
INSTALLFOLDER=$(PROJECTNAME).app

CC=arm-apple-darwin9-gcc
LD=$(CC)
LDFLAGS = -arch arm -lobjc 
LDFLAGS += -framework CoreFoundation 
LDFLAGS += -framework Foundation 
LDFLAGS += -framework UIKit 
LDFLAGS += -framework QuartzCore
LDFLAGS += -framework CoreGraphics 
LDFLAGS += -framework CoreAudio 
LDFLAGS += -framework AudioToolbox
LDFLAGS += -framework AVFoundation
LDFLAGS += -L"/usr/lib"
LDFLAGS += -F"/System/Library/Frameworks"
LDFLAGS += -F"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks"
LDFLAGS += -bind_at_load
LDFLAGS += -multiply_defined suppress

CFLAGS = -I"/var/include" 
CFLAGS += -I"/usr/include"
CFLAGS += -I"/var/include/c++/4.0.0"
CFLAGS += -I"/var/include/c++/4.0.0/arm-apple-darwin9"
CFLAGS += -I"./Classes"
CFLAGS += -F"/System/Library/Frameworks" 
CFLAGS += -F"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks" 
CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -Wall 
CFLAGS += -DMAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED=1050

BUILDDIR=./build/2.0
SRCDIR=./Classes
RESDIR=./Resources
OBJS=$(patsubst %.m,%.o,$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.m))
OBJS+=$(patsubst %.mm,%.o,$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.mm))
OBJS+=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c))
OBJS+=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp))
RESOURCES=$(wildcard $(RESDIR)/*)

all:    dist

CFLAGS += -include Prefix.h


$(PROJECTNAME): $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o:    %.m
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o:    %.mm
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o:    %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o:    %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

dist:   $(PROJECTNAME)
    /bin/rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)
    /bin/mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)/$(APPFOLDER)
    /bin/cp $(RESDIR)/* $(BUILDDIR)/$(APPFOLDER)
    /bin/cp Info.plist $(BUILDDIR)/$(APPFOLDER)/Info.plist
    @echo "APPL????" > $(BUILDDIR)/$(APPFOLDER)/PkgInfo
    /usr/bin/ldid -S $(PROJECTNAME)
    /bin/cp $(PROJECTNAME) $(BUILDDIR)/$(APPFOLDER)

install: dist
    /bin/cp -r $(BUILDDIR)/$(APPFOLDER) /Applications/$(INSTALLFOLDER)
    @echo "Application $(INSTALLFOLDER) installed"
    killall SpringBoard

uninstall:
    /bin/rm -fr /Applications/$(INSTALLFOLDER)
    killall SpringBoard

reinstall: dist
    /bin/rm -fr /Applications/$(INSTALLFOLDER)
    /bin/cp -r $(BUILDDIR)/$(APPFOLDER) /Applications/$(INSTALLFOLDER)
    @echo "Application $(INSTALLFOLDER) installed"

clean:
    @rm -f $(SRCDIR)/*.o
    @rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)
    @rm -f $(PROJECTNAME)
```

It is important to note that Prefix.h used to be a precompiled header but I just changed it to a header file and told make to include it in all my source files.

The quick fix that I made for the problem of not including the final quote was:

changing:

```
$(PROJECTNAME): $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

to:

```
$(PROJECTNAME): $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^"
```

To restate my question after that long post. Did my change to the Makefile somehow cause it to not load the _main symbol?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out my actual app name given by PROJECTNAME had a space in it. I removed the space my quick fix and changed LD from apple-arm-darwin9-gcc to apple-arm-darwin9-g++. after that it worked.